# How to get a tkinter Label to update itself?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a Label which i want to use as the display for my calculator - when a button is pressed I want the display to be updated. I am trying to set the displayText so I should be able to type 01 or 10.

```
from tkinter import *
gui = Tk()
buttonValues = []
displayText = StringVar(gui)
def press(buttonValue):
    buttonValues.append(buttonValue)
    display = Label(gui, text=displayText.set(''.join(str(i) for i in buttonValues)))
    display.grid(row=0)
    display.update()
    "print(''.join(str(i) for i in buttonValues))"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    button0 = Button(gui, text=' 0 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                     command=lambda: press(0), height=1, width=7)
    button0.grid(row=2, column=0)
    button1 = Button(gui, text=' 1 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                     command=lambda: press(1), height=1, width=7)
    button1.grid(row=2, column=1)

    gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to happen by setting the `Label` `textvariable` option to the `displayText` string variable and then calling its `set()` method whenever you want it to change. It's not necessary to repeatedly create a `display` widget nor do anything else — it will happen automatically.

```
from tkinter import *

gui = Tk()
buttonValues = []
displayText = StringVar(value='')

def press(buttonValue):
    buttonValues.append(buttonValue)
    displayText.set(''.join(map(str, buttonValues)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    display = Label(gui, textvariable=displayText)
    display.grid(row=0)

    button0 = Button(gui, text=' 0 ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press(0))
    button0.grid(row=2, column=0)
    button1 = Button(gui, text=' 1 ', fg='black', bg='red', command=lambda: press(1))
    button1.grid(row=2, column=1)

    gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mickey: Doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: It still doesn't update the display when i press the buttons

Comment: When you create the `Label`, make sure its passed `textvariable=displayText`.

Comment: I used displayText.configure and reconfigured the text to update the label

Comment: If you use `textvariable=` as shown, there's be no need to call `configure()`. — the label will update automatically whenever `displayText.set()` is called.

Answer (score -1):

Using Python 3.12.0rc3, Windows.

> when a button is pressed I want the display to be updated. I am trying
> to set the displayText so I should be able to type 01 or 10.

Using same code as @ martineau's script.

To used `configure`.

Replace this:

```
def press(buttonValue):
    buttonValues.append(buttonValue)
    displayText.set(''.join(map(str, buttonValues)))
```

to:

```
def press(buttonValue):
    buttonValues.append(buttonValue)
    #displayText.set(''.join(map(str, buttonValues)))
    display.configure(text=displayText.set(''.join(str(i) for i in buttonValues)))
```

Screenshot:

[image]